# Setuid directory permission implies execute permission?

Tags: permissions

Does setting `u+s` on a directory imply `u+x`?

Comment: See the wikipedia article on the topic, Unix File System permissions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's a difference ;-)

```
# ls -l x
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 27 20:07 x
# chmod u+s x
# ls -l x
-rwSr--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 27 20:07 x
# chmod u+x x
# ls -l x
-rwsr--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 27 20:07 x
```

See, e.g.
http://www.linuxnix.com/2011/12/suid-set-suid-linuxunix.html

You see the difference more clearly

- Capital S: `chmod 4655` (no execute)
- small s: `chmod 4755` (execute set)

For when you would need capital S? Good question...